# why cant my printf pick up my user input?

Tags: c

I have this

```
void main(int argnum, char** input)
{
   int a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, e=0, f=0, g=0, h=0, i=0, j=0, k=0, l=0, m=0, n=0, o=0, p=0;

   printf("Enter the numbers from 1 to 16, in any order(separate by comma) : ");

   scanf_s("%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f, &g, &h, &i, &j, &k, &l, &m, &n, &o, &p);
   printf("%d " "%d " "%d " "%d \n", a, b, c, d);
   printf("%d " "%d " "%d " "%d \n", e, f, g, h);
   printf("%d " "%d " "%d " "%d \n", i, j, k, l);
   printf("%d " "%d " "%d " "%d \n", m, n, o, p); 
  
}
```

my display is

```
a 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

for some reason my variables other than a, arent being caught.. whats wrong?

Comment: BTW, any reason you're writing `"%d " "%d " "%d " "%d \n"` instead of the equivalent, and more readable, `"%d %d %d %d \n"`?

Comment: Even with the corrected quotation your request to `..."(separate by comma)  : "` will fail unless you include the actual `','` separators in your *format string*.

Comment: Unless you are programming in a *freestanding environment* (without the benefit of any OS), in a standards conforming implementation, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char **argv`).  See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: A preferred approach would be to read the entire line of user input into a buffer (character array) and then parse the integer values from the array with `strtol()` (or at minimum `sscanf()`). That way, it doesn't matter what the user separates the numbers by, you can simply pick out the integer values and then validate that all 16 values were entered. Input of `"1dog2cats 3fleas4frogs5birds 6frogs 7 or 8,9,10 mice? and 11 pipers 12 drummers 13 14 15 16"` would work fine...

Comment: Using an array of 16-`int` makes more sense than 16 separate integer variables.

Comment: Read it as a single string, then parse.

Comment: Why is `printf()` not working?  You don't even know if `scanf_s()` worked - you're not checking the return value to see if it worked or not.  And `scanf_s()` is **no safer** than the C standard function `scanf()`.  `scanf_s()` is not portable and `scanf()` hasn't been deprecated by anyone other than Microsoft...

Answer (score 2):

> (separate by comma)

If you're separating the numbers with commas, the second and subsequent scans will fails, because there's no way to turn a comma into an integer.

Scanning for an `%d` integer will:

- skip white space (which does not include commas); then
- scan as many characters as needed to populate an integer, up until the first character that's not part of an integer.

If the first non-whitespace character is a comma, that's not suitable for an integer. Easiest solution is probably just to tell user to separate with spaces rather than commas.

---

Let's begin with a cut-down version that exhibits the same behaviour (and with single strings rather than those disparate ones):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a=0, b=0;

    printf("Enter numbers from 1 to 2 in any order (separate by comma): ");

    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
}
```

Entering `1,2` for that gives you `1 0` as per your code. Entering `1 2` (space-separated rather than comma) gives you `1 2`, which is what you're after.

Of course, if you *need* the commas, you can put that into the format string as well:

```
scanf("%d ,%d", &a, &b);
```

This will:

- `%d` - skip optional whitespace and read integer;
- `<space>`: skip whitespace before comma;
- `,`: skip comma;
- `%d` - skip optional whitespace and read integer.

---

Of course, it goes without saying that you should always *check* things that can fail, if that failure can affect you adversely:

```
if (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) != 2) { // expect two things scanned
    fprintf(stderr, "Something went horribly wrong!\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(int argnum, char** input)
{
   int a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, e=0, f=0, g=0, h=0, i=0, j=0, k=0, l=0, m=0, n=0, o=0, p=0;

   printf("Enter the numbers from 1 to 16, in any order(separate by comma) : ");

   scanf("%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f, &g, &h, &i, &j, &k, &l, &m, &n, &o, &p);
   printf("%d " "%d " "%d " "%d \n", a, b, c, d);
   printf("%d " "%d " "%d " "%d \n", e, f, g, h);
   printf("%d " "%d " "%d " "%d \n", i, j, k, l);
   printf("%d " "%d " "%d " "%d \n", m, n, o, p); 
  
}
```

after taking each value from the keyboard please press enter button it will work with this code

Comment: You have a typo in `#include`